# Xamarin - Binding username from login to toolbarItem

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, data-binding

I try to do exactly what the title says, I have searched and searched and nothing.

Hope anyone can help, here is the problem:

I got an app that you don't need to register, just need to log in, the data comes from a web service. Here is the login method.

```
public async Task<string> LoginAsync(string user, string pass, string company)
    {
        RssUser userInfos = new RssUser{ user = user, pass = pass, company = "PROJECTO_GPS" };
        RootObject ro = new RootObject();
        ro.rssUser = userInfos;

        var jsonObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ro);
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonObj.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
            {
                RequestUri = new Uri("http://evolus.ddns.net/Q4Evolution/php/phpGps/BOLoginGps.php"),
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                Content = content
            };
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            string dataResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            Debug.WriteLine(dataResult);
            return dataResult;
        }
    }
```

And this is the Rss Class:

```
 public class RssUser
    {

        private AppService _log = new AppService();
        public string user { get; set; }
        public string pass { get; set; }
        public string company { get; set; }

        public ICommand LoginCommmand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async () =>
                {
                    await _log.LoginAsync(user, pass, company);

                });
            }
        }

    }

   public class RootObject
     {
    public RssUser rssUser { get; set; }
     }
```

This is working fine, my question is how I get the username of this login to bind to the toolbar that's going to appear in the page after the login.

Here some code of the Xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:AppQ4evo.ViewModels"
         x:Class="AppQ4evo.Menu"
         NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewModels:RssUser/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Name="icon" Order="Primary" Icon="srw_circular.png" Priority="0" />
    <ToolbarItem Icon="baseline_account_circle_black_18dp.png" Order="Primary" Text="{Binding user}" Priority="0" />
    <ToolbarItem Name="LogOut" Order="Primary" Text="Log Out" Priority="0" Clicked="LogOut_Clicked"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>...
```

So the thing is this `Text="{Binding user}"` i have seen a lot of different ways of binding, but I really can´t make any of them work. Hope someone gives me some light on this. 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the `RssUser` class that you're setting as the binding context?

Comment: I edit, is there now @Andrew

Comment: It doesn't look User is implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. This is what tells the view something has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

The `RssUser` class is not implementing INotifyPropertyChange, so the view is never being told that `user` has changed. An example of what your class may look like after implementing the interface would be something like:

```
class RssUser: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private AppService _log = new AppService();
    string user;
    string pass;
    string company;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   public ICommand LoginCommmand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                await _log.LoginAsync(user, pass, company);

            });
        }
    }

    public string User
    {
        set
        {
            if (user != value)
            {
                user = value;

                 PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(User)))
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return user;
        }
    }
    // You would also want to similar for pass and company.
}
```

Finally you would want to update your binding to match the public User property: `Text="{Binding User}"`

Note that it is possible to put the property changed logic in a base class and inherit your VM's from that.

Comment: okok almost get everyting you said, but i don´t understand where that dateTime come from?

Comment: Oops, sorry. I modified that example from the Microsoft docs, but apparently missed that when I was changing it. See my updated answer.

Comment: I have try your solution, but is steel not working. it dysplay like the button on the toolbar but with no name on it, just like a invisibel button. @Andrew